# Prevent jquery slider's image show in the page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using this jquery and html for change the clicked image on a display div it works fine but the issue is when i click a image in the display div its open in the page itself. How to Make the image as it as when user click on it.

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
                   jQuery('div#thumbs img').click(function () {

                jQuery('#foo a').prop('href', jQuery(this).prop('src'));
                jQuery('#foo img').prop('src', jQuery(this).prop('src'));
                return false;
              })
              </script>
```

**my html**

```
          <div id="foo">
        <a href="#">
         <img src="images/demo_slider.jpg" name="Display" id="display" /></a>
            </div>
             <br />
            <div id="thumbs">
       <img src="images/a.jpg" width="56" height="56" alt="" />
       <img src="images/b.jpg" width="56" height="56" alt="" />
       <img src="images/c.jpg" width="56" height="56" alt="" />
      <img src="images/d.jpg" width="56" height="56" alt="" />
         </div>

       </div>
```

edit:

If the user click the thumbs image it load to the div foo. then the user click the image in foo the clicked image opens in the same page(as the basic html functionality like open image in new tab) i need to prevent the image open on click.

Comment: Can you explain better what the issue is?

Comment: I don't understand, when you click on the img with id=display whatyou want to happen?

Comment: @FakeHeal: if we click the image its shows in the separate page again the user need to push back button and come back to  the slider page.so, make the image not open if user click on it.

Comment: @Krish http://jsfiddle.net/FakeHeal/DYuJJ/1/ This is an example how your code works. I don't understand which one opens in a separate page?

Comment: @FakeHeal: yes your are right if you click the selected image its retains same but in my case its opens in the same window

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: i put the issue in my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
$('#foo a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but you could try adding preventDefault:

```
jQuery("#foo a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Did you mean something like that...